# semop failed invalid argument aix 7.1

Tags: semaphore, aix

In our project, we are using semaphore to synchronize between parent and child process. perform the semaphore operation and delete the semaphore for every time synchronize.

After a couple of weeks later semop operation failed with "invalid Argument"

```
 sembuf.sem_num = 0;
 sembuf.sem_op =  1;
 sembuf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;

 ret = semop( semid, &sembuf, 1 ); --> invalid arguments couple of weeks later.
```

semid is proper, I am not seeing any semaphore leak due to the particular process.

```
In man page i could see the possible reason for invalid argument could see below:
EINVAL  The SemaphoreID parameter is not a valid semaphore identifier.
EINVAL  The number of individual semaphores for which the calling process requests a SEM_UNDO flag would exceed the limit.

I am suspecting the point 2.
It is multithreaded process. So Howmany semaphore can be used at a time for a procees ?
What is the limit of "SEM_UNDO" ?
1) how to make sure that EINVAL is due to "SEM_UNDO" flag exceed limit. ?.
2) how to avoid the exceed limit ?
3) Is there any kernel variable needs to be configured for this issue (in AIX most of the kernals are dynamic)?
```

Thanks in advance for helping this

Comment: You might have deleted the semaphore (`semctl(IPC_REMOVE)`) -- perhaps in another process/thread. Edit: this may happen when accidentally reusing the same `key` in `semget`.

Comment: We are creating semaphore everytime using semget and remove the semaphore once the synchronisation is done. But after a while , even though we create new semaphore without any error, semaphore operation is failing with invalid argument

Comment: Well, then you know what the reason is: another thread/process destroyed the semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

As I've already written in comment, another thread/process of yours has deleted the semaphore you were trying to use. You are not supposed to create and destroy the semaphore at every usage.

Off: I admit SYSV-semaphores have a little quirk, i.e. they are created with value=0 which means *locked* (or *reserved*, *acquired*), instead of value=1 (meaning *free* (or *available*)). This can be fixed with a simple trick, example program: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/sysv_sem_test.c